# jquery i18n properties ie fails on eval line

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internationalization

Hi I've developped a website using jquery and the jquery i18n plugin so I could re-use my old properties files for internationalization everything goes fine in FF, Opera, Chrome but when I try IE8 my page doesn't load the way I want it and it fails on an eval function inside the i18n plugin.
Does anyone has had this problem before and knows how to work around on IE, if so any help would be much appreciated, the line this is happening on is 327 position 4.


cheers J.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eval function in the i18n code basically creates global variables. This is caused by using either vars or both as the `mode` for loading the property files. IE8 will fail when trying to set these. The fix is to use the `map` mode when you load the [property files](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/). This way the properties will be only available via a `$.i18n.prop` call.

Example of using the map mode:

```
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name:'Messages', 
    path:'bundle/', 
    mode:'map',
    language:'pt_PT', 
    callback: function() {
    }
});
```